# Improve efficiency by removing concat

Tags: haskell

I'm attempting to improve the efficiency of a particular function in my code which is taking up a large amount of the runtime. After profiling, I believe this is because of the concat within the code. How could I go about improving this code to be quicker?

```
chunk :: C -> [A] -> [[A]]
chunk c = go []
  where s = Set.fromList (map snd (Map.toList c))
        go :: [A] -> [A] -> [[A]]
        go l []     = [l | member l s]
        go l (x:xs) = if member l s then l : go [x] xs
                                    else go (l ++ [x]) xs
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Choose a structure with O(1) snoc and cons.  I think dlist and sequence should be interesting to you.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I took a look at the DList module, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do pattern matching on them. Is that possible? Or should I rewrite that part of the code?

Comment: Afterwards call toList to retain your old api.

Comment: There's also the "poor man's queue" which would probably work well here: `type Q a = ([a], [a])`. Cons'd elements go in the left, snoc'd elements go in the right in reverse order. You can use `toList (xs, ys) = xs ++ reverse ys` to do all the expensive snocs at once.

Comment: The "poor man's dequeue" Daniel Wagner suggests is likely to be quite good. You should be able to convert that `Map` to a `Set` quicker using `fromAscendingList` or whatever it's called. There may even be a faster way, and depending on the size of the `Map` it might even be better to skip the conversion and just look for elements in the `Map`.

Comment: I'm not seeing how I would be able to use the poor man's queue here, since I need the full list to call member on the Set. How could you implement around that?

Comment: Write an `Ord` instance for your poor man's queue.  It may not be quite as efficient as comparing lists, but it's probably better than the O(n^2) behavior from appending to the wrong end of a list...

Comment: @thehandyman Oh, wait, you only ever snoc. Why not just always cons, and "remember" that the list is reversed...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution would be to use [`Seq`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.3/docs/Data-Sequence.html), where *snoc* operation is *O(1)*. This involves converting the input first and then converting the result back, which would be worth, unless the set is large compared to the average length of the lists.

There is however another problem, and that is testing the membership of the lists (or similar structures). Comparison or testing equality on lists is *O(n)*, and in your case, where you test the membership of a list that is likely a sub-list of a list contained in the set, the testing will indeed be *Ω(n)*. So even then, the complexity of `chunk` could be in the order of *O(n^2)* where *n* is the length of the list argument.

It seems that using a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) would be a better solution. A trie is much more efficient than a set of lists in both memory and time complexity. And especially useful for this case is its operation which allows you to take a sub-trie constructed by filtering all elements with a given prefix in *O(1)*.

An example code (untested):

```
chunk :: C -> [A] -> [[A]]
chunk c = go trie
  where trie = Trie.fromList (map snd (Map.toList c))
        go :: Trie -> [A] -> [A] -> [[A]]
        go s l []     = [reverse l | Trie.member [] s]
        go s l (x:xs)
          | Trie.member [] s = reverse l : go (Trie.lookupPrefix [x] trie) xs
          | otherwise        = go (x : l) (Trie.lookupPrefix [x] s)
```

Now each step of `go` should take only *O(n)* amortized cost (the only non-*O(1)* operation is `reverse`, but this is *O(1)* amortized, as reversing a *k*-element list occurs only once after *k* steps).

And now we can also make a further improvement: When the sub-trie is empty, we know we'll never return an additional element, as we'll never reach the matching case. So we could add a pattern to the top

```
        go s _ _ | Trie.null s = []
```

Package [list-trie](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/list-tries-0.6.1/docs/Data-ListTrie-Set.html) seem to be just perfect for this.